# Disable html property using viewbag

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to render a dropdown list as diabled once the on change event has been triggered. I am passing the disabled flag in a viewbag from the controller on httppost. However, the viewbag's name is displaying in teh html flag rather than just the value. Please see my code below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown", ViewData["dropdown"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control",  id = "dropbox", onchange = "this.form.submit();", ViewBag.propertydisable})
```

in my controller

```
ViewBag.propertydisable = "disabled";
```

How it renders the html:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="dropbox" name="searchparams" propertydisable="disabled" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
    <option value="">--Select Budget holder--</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="opt">option2</option>
</select>
```

How i am wanting it to render is

```html
<select class="form-control" id="dropbox" name="searchparams" disabled onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">--Select Budget holder--</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="opt">option2</option>
</select>
```

So that the end result once the postback is complete will be disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build an object defining the html attributes based on the `ViewBag` property

```
@{ var attributes = ViewBag.propertydisable ? (object)new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled"} : (object)new { @class = "form-control"}; }
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown", ViewData["dropdown"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--Select--", attributes)
```

Note that you should be setting the `ViewBag` property as

```
ViewBag.propertydisable = true;
```

Side note: Use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting your markup with behavior. Not sure why you changing the `id` attribute from the default `"dropdown"` to `"dropbox"` but the following assumes you delete the `id="dropbox"` attribute

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
  $('#form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all instead of inline scripting use unobtrusive js. And also you use wrong overload.

Following code should work :

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown",yourlist,new { @class = "form-control",  id = "dropbox",disabled=ViewBag.propertydisable})
```

Update:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


            $('#dropdown').change(function() {

                $('#form').submit();

            });
```

Comment: I have tried that and the property  comes as disabled without the postback being triggered, even when i set the viewbag value as false.

Comment: @user2055227 that's right, just the presence of "disabled" will disable it, regardless of the part after "=".

Comment: so its the js code that is wrong. see the updated code

Comment: @persianDeveloper that's a good example of unobtrusive javascript, but it will be difficult to trigger the change when the drop down is still disabled.

Comment: @Crowcoder actually I am littble bit confused about logic case it is not abvoius from question. Anyway even in none unobtrusive js way it could not trigger due to begin disable

Comment: @persianDeveloper my point was that the problem has nothing to do with the javascript.

Comment: i agree with @crowcoder, problem has nothing to do with javascript. the question is about the viewbag

Comment: So explain your scenario completely. You can set viewbag in httpost action easily and use it again or if your form should be send once you can save disable in a session key.

Comment: the problem is where the contents of viewbag comes as "propertydisable="disabled"" when i want them to come as "disabled". hope that helps

Comment: `disabled=ViewBag.propertydisable` will always set the control to be disabled! - `disabled` or `disabled="disabled"` or `disabled="false" or `disabled="anyValueAtAll"` will all do exactly the same thing - they will set the `disabled` attribute (although only the first 2 are valid html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems hacky to me, but you can conditionally render the element this way by changing your propertydisable to a bool:

```
@{
    if(Viewbag.propertydisable)
    {
        Html.DropDownList("dropdown", 
            ViewData["dropdown"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
            "--Select--", 
            new { @class = "form-control",  
                    id = "dropbox", 
                    onchange = "this.form.submit();", 
                    disabled = "disabled"});
        }
    else
    {
        Html.DropDownList("dropdown", 
            ViewData["dropdown"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
            "--Select--", 
            new { @class = "form-control",  
                    id = "dropbox", 
                    onchange = "this.form.submit();"});
    }
}
```